# Laravel login and register forms on the same page in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, laravel, authentication

[image: Login and Register forms on the same page]

From default auth and register sistem that comes with Laravel 5.2,
Just made a simple view, that could be the welcome page, and to include the login and register forms.
At the moment, if any button is pressed, the validation checks and finds errors from both forms, and are highlighted all of them which are required.
So what is the best solution to include them and maybe a separate validation for each?

I tried to change the default login sistem to be different from the register form input names, but i think there is a chain, due to validation and adding input values into database.

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('login_email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="login_email" value="{{ old('login_email') }}">
         @if ($errors->has('login_email'))
              <span class="help-block">
                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('login_email') }}</strong>
              </span>
         @endif
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('login_password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="login_password">
                @if ($errors->has('login_password'))
                     <span class="help-block">
                          <strong>{{ $errors->first('login_password') }}</strong>
                     </span>
               @endif
          </div>
      </div>
```

As it can be seen, just changed the email and password input names from 'email' to 'login_email' and from 'password' to 'login_password'

Any quick and efficient solutions/ideas are welcome

Comment: say, have you changed the names in the `Controller@Method` as well?

Comment: Yes, i chenged those too, and then i got an error from SQL. It seems to compare the input names with columns from Users table, but i think it's a good ideea to edit the core of attempt() method, becouse in the following code, the array contains those input names:                               if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
        }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of changing input names, just Override trait function and call it from the overriden function...

With this done, we can store a session value that tell us from where the auth attempt is coming from login or register form!

```
    use AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers {
    AuthenticatesUsers::redirectPath insteadof RegistersUsers;
    AuthenticatesUsers::getGuard insteadof RegistersUsers;
    login as traitLogin;
    register as traitRegister;
}

// Override trait function and call it from the overriden function
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //Set session as 'login'
    Session::put('last_auth_attempt', 'login');
    //The trait is not a class. You can't access its members directly.
    return $this->traitLogin($request);
}


public function register(Request $request)
{
    //Set session as 'register'
    Session::put('last_auth_attempt', 'register');
    //The trait is not a class. You can't access its members directly.
    return $this->traitRegister($request);
}
```

and in your View.blade file just check your errors with your Session value ...

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') && Session::get('last_auth_attempt') == 'login' ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

        @if ($errors->has('email') && Session::get('last_auth_attempt') == 'login')
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

With this you can check if button pressed is from login ou register button

Comment: Why not use session()->flash()?

Answer (score 3):

Another quick but  maybe not that elegant solution would be inserting a hidden field  into  the  login-form

`<input type="hidden" name="loginform" value="1">`

and then just check it with email- and password-errors in both forms.

At the login-form something like:

`@if($errors->has('password') && !old('loginform'))`

And at the registration-form something like:

`@if($errors->has('password') && old('loginform'))`

No server-side code needed.
Laravel version 5.*

Answer (score 1):

I figured out:
In AuthenticatesUsers trait, change every 'email' to 'login_email' and 'password' to 'login_password'.
Also, the login attempt will use these as credentials array keys, so edit this function to:

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'login_password');
    $credentials['email'] = $credentials['login_email'];
    $credentials['password'] = $credentials['login_password'];
    unset($credentials['login_email']);
    unset($credentials['login_password']);
    return $credentials;
    //return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'login_password');
}
```

Now everything works fine.

Comment: You should copy this method into your AuthController and edit it there (to override it), but your code works like a charm :)

Comment: @Spidey, can you share complete code please? I mean what have you done in View and in controller and routes?

Comment: @XahedKamal . The code is too long to add it here. I have added to the following link and the PASSWORD is: laravel      http://textcrypt.com/y8zviqqP9z

Comment: @Spidey, Thanks. But seems you added wrong controller? I dont see any `showLogin` function

Comment: @XahedKamal, is the same function, just rename it. http://textcrypt.com/yMB5z5ZpZD    Password: laravel

Comment: @Spidey, seems your function is for dates or something. I don't see it handling Login!

Comment: @XahedKamal, that's becouse the auth it's build in from Illuminate/Auth. i didn't make any changes to it. the only changes i've made are right here. maybe you forgot to install the auth system. you can do it L5.2 with: php artisan make:auth

Comment: I'm used `make:auth`. I don't know how you achieved getting both Login and Registration form working. But luckily i got it working. I've posted the solution in Laracast.com forum

Comment: @XahedKamal do you have a link to that post?

Comment: @cora here is the link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-login-form-and-registration-form-in-same-page

Answer (score 1):

In your AuthController set this in the constructor.

```
/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    Session::put('last_auth_attempt', $request->auth_attempt);
}
```

You have to send in a hidden input the value of "auth_attempt". In that way you can know in the view what you were trying to do either login or register.

Register form:

```
...     

<input type="hidden" name="auth_attempt" value="register">

...
```

Login form:

```
...     

<input type="hidden" name="auth_attempt" value="login">

...
```

Then in your validations or where you need it you can use the following to validate if you were trying to login or register.

```
      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('lastName') && Session::get('last_auth_attempt') == 'register' ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="name">Last Name</label>
        <input id="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" value="{{ old('lastName') }}">

        @if ($errors->has('lastName') && Session::get('last_auth_attempt') == 'register')
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('lastName') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
      </div>
```