# how to get SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$email' in 'where clause' solved in my case

Tags: php, laravel-5

> **Note :-** I'm new to Laravel world.

I have a Migration as

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table-> increments('id');
            $table-> string('email');            
            $table-> string('username');            
            $table-> string('password');
            $table-> string('first_name')-> nullable();
            $table-> string('last_name')-> nullable();
            $table-> string('location')-> nullable();
            $table-> string('remember_token')-> nullable();            
            $table-> timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

and now I want to implement login functionality using the form

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('auth.signin')}}">                      
    <input type="text" name="login_email" class="header-login-input z-depth-2" placeholder="email"/>

    <input type="password" name="login_password" class="header-login-input z-depth-2" placeholder="password"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token()}}">
    <button name="action">Login</button>
</form>
```

at this point my login controller is

```
class LoginAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

        $this -> validate($request, [           
            'login_email' => 'required',
            'login_password' => 'required',
            ]);

        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['login_email',
            'login_password']))) {
            return  redirect()-> back()-> with('info', "Could not sign you with those details!!!");
        }       

        return  redirect()-> route('home') -> with('info', "Welcome to home, You are signed in");
    }}
```

when I run the app I get error

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 673:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'login_email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `login_email` = some@wi.con limit 1)
```

at this point I did a change that is in postSignIn() I wrote

```
$email = $request->input('login_email');
        $password = $request->input('login_password');

        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['$email',
            '$password']))) {
            return  redirect()-> back()-> with('info', "Could not sign you with those details!!!");
        }
```

but still getting

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 673:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `$email` is null limit 1)
```

### Question

My Question is how can I pass values to

```
Auth::attempt($request->only(['$email', '$password']))
```

so that my issue could be solved.

### UPDATE

If I change login form to

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('auth.signin')}}">                      
        <input type="text" name="email" class="header-login-input z-depth-2" placeholder="email"/>

        <input type="password" name="password" class="header-login-input z-depth-2" placeholder="password"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token()}}">
        <button name="action">Login</button>
    </form>
```

then this works, there is an other problem that there are Sign-up and Log-in forms on same page and in validation there comes a conflict between those two forms, any help in this case please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's read the error message

> QueryException in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'login_email' in 'where clause' (SQL:
>   select * from `users` where `login_email` = some@wi.con limit 1)

It states that you do not have `login_email` column in the `users` table. And this is very true. In the migration you have created a different column named `email`.

Check the [Laravel manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users)

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

And the explanation following

> So, in the example above, the user will be retrieved by the value of
>   the email column. If the user is found, the hashed password stored in
>   the database will be compared with the hashed password value passed to
>   the method via the array. If the two hashed passwords match an
>   authenticated session will be started for the user.

The code should look like this (I can not easily check it, this is my guess)

```
if (Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $request->input('login_email'),
    'password' => $request->input('login_password')
])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
```

Note that like it is explained in the documentation you provide an array with keys `email` and `password` which match your DB structure and proper values from the form.

Comment: Please see my update and make sure my issue is clearly described.

Comment: You can leave form as it was before changes and try my code. I think in this case you do not have any conflicts with other forms.

Comment: Man! Sorry I posted comment before checking your code and yeah! Your code works fine thanks a ton.

Comment: I've updated your question to make it clear for future reference. The issue was that DB column names are different from the form column names and you have to specify mapping. This is why you can not use `$request->only()` method but should manually create the array with correct keys matching DB table columns.

Answer (score 1):

$email and $password set as string with ' and not with ".

There are 2 options

```
$request->only(["$email","$password"])
// or
$request->only([$email,$password]) // this is the best option
```

**Example :**

```
$test = 54;

echo '$test'; // return $test
echo "$test"; // return 54
echo $test; // return 54
```

You should use " when you have text with variables like :

```
echo "Number = $test";
```

Comment: Sorry, but still getting _Unknown column 'some@tt' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `some@tt` = and `wrwerwerwe` is null limit 1_ error.

Comment: ok, so don't use "$email" and just use "email". I think in your case, you don't search the user's email field but the "email" field

Comment: Here __some@tt__ is value of `$email`, and so on

Comment: I think this link can help you : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/authattempt-throwing-invalid-user-credentials-for-valid-credentials-too-in-laravel-5 to understand how it works

Comment: Please see my update and make sure my issue is clearly described.

Comment: @MiniCascading There is already an answer about your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097071/laravel-login-and-register-forms-on-the-same-page-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109434/discussion-between-mathieu-lescaudron-and-mini-cascading).