# Register and Login form in one page in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, forms, laravel, error-handling

I was creating a page which have both register and login in one page.

My code looks like this

```
<div class="w3-display-container w3-white">
    <div style="white-space:nowrap;" class="container">
        <h2>Already have an account?</h2><hr>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 w3-margin-bottom">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'login', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::label('email', 'Enter Your Email...', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    {{ Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'email...', 'value' => old('email')]) }}
                    <span class="{{ $errors->has('email') ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' : '' }}"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::label('password', 'Enter Your Password...', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'password...']) }}
                    <span class="{{ $errors->has('password') ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' : '' }}"></span>
                </div>
                {{ Form::submit('Log in', ['class' => 'btn btn-success w3-margin-top']) }}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="w3-display-container w3-white">
    <div style="white-space:nowrap;" class="container">
        <h2>New Here?</h2><hr>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 w3-margin-bottom">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'register']) !!}
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::label('name', 'Username...', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'username...']) }}
                    <span class="{{ $errors->has('name') ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' : '' }}"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email...', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    {{ Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'email...']) }}
                    <span class="{{ $errors->has('email') ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' : '' }}"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password...', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'passsword...']) }}
                    <span class="{{ $errors->has('password') ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' : '' }}"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirm Password...', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'confirm password...']) }}
                    <span class="{{ $errors->has('password') ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback' : '' }}"></span>
                </div>
                {{ Form::submit('Sign Up', ['class' => 'btn btn-success w3-margin-top']) }}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use bootstrap and w3schools for styling.

The problem which i get is that when i submit any one form with empty inputs it give me error in both the forms.
That is (for example), when i submit the login form with empty email and password fields, the error shows in login form and register form, that the field is empty.

**How can i fix it?
I want to show errors differently.

Still have any doubt about my code or my question please comment below.**
I even  looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097071/laravel-login-and-register-forms-on-the-same-page-in-laravel-5-2) for help but it was laravel 5.2, laravel 5.3 have different auth route system

Comment: Could you tell specific case and input values for which you are getting errors in both forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are showing the errors on both of them `{{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : '' }}` That string of code is in both the register and the login form so therefore the errors will show on them both.

One solution could be to create the validation yourself using PHP & jQuery/JavaScript, This way you can fully customise the errors etc. It would take a bit longer and is slightly harder to do but its doable